# Design Pattern for dynamically configurable objects

Tags: design-patterns, configuration

I have a flash based browser animation which loads a xml based configuration file and setts up an external callback called: `setConfig( xmlString ):void`. I also have the configuration file editable in codemirror beside the animation. Each time the configuration file is saved the new file should be injected into flash (without reloading it).

I am searching for a Design Pattern to implement this into flash properly. All Objects should be notified by changes in configuration and react if necessary. What can be a good approach? I am curious for all kind of suggestions!

Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

The [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern.

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object,
>   called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to
>   implement distributed event handling systems.